# Join two Pandas dataframes that have common, duplicated indices without doing the Cartesian product

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to join two Pandas dataframes that have common, duplicated indices without doing the Cartesian product? E.g.:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'event':['A','C','D']}, index=[1.,3.,3.])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'event':['B','C']}, index=[2.,3.])
```

Note event `C` is recorded in both frames, and `C` and `D` both have the same index value (a timestamp).

```
df1.join(df2,how='outer',lsuffix='1',rsuffix='2')
```

gives:

```
    event1 event2
1.0      A    NaN
2.0    NaN      B
3.0      C      C
3.0      D      C
```

The (`C`,`C`) and (`D`,`C`) rows are the Cartesian product of `C` and `D` in `df1` and `C` in `df2`. I want row 4 to be just (`D`, `NaN`), since `D` only appears in `df1` and not in `df2`, i.e.:

```
    event1 event2
1.0      A    NaN
2.0    NaN      B
3.0      C      C
3.0      D    NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to `merge` on a second `cumcount`ed index column:

```
i, j = [
    x.set_index(x.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True) for x in (df1, df2)
]

i.merge(
    j, 
    left_index=True, 
    right_index=True, 
    how='outer', 
    suffixes=('1', '2')
).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

    event1 event2
1.0      A    NaN
2.0    NaN      B
3.0      C      C
3.0      D    NaN
```

Comment: @msleigh It generalises to the point that your example asks for. If you have any further use cases, I'd recommend adding a [mcve] that reflects it.

Comment: Although it definitely answers the question, this doesn't generalise to the case where `df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'event':['B','D']}, index=[2.,3.])`. However I realised using the event ID itself as the second index column works just as well, i.e.: `... x.set_index(x['event'], append=True) for x in (df1, df2)]`.

Comment: @msleigh Okay, fair enough. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Agreed, I already accepted and upvoted your answer... My comment was to add additional info.